# Same milliseconds for two different times in java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I need to convert a 24 hour date format for a given string into milliseconds. But I get the same milliseconds for 00:10:00 and 12:10:00. This is my code sample; please assist me.

```
DateFormat formate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); 

formate.parse("2013-10-31 12:10:00").getTime(); //  return 1383158400000

formate.parse("2013-10-31 00:10:00").getTime();  // return 1383158400000
```

I am using 24 hours format, but I get the same result for 2 different times. Where is the mistake? Please help me to find out the problem.

Comment: you mean to use `HH` instead of `hh`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the 12-hour `hh` format; use the 24-hour `HH` (capitalized) format.

```
DateFormat formate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

- [`SimpleDateFormat` date symbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> H Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
>
> h Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

Without AM/PM marker, the date-time parser considers the hour in 24-Hour format for which the symbol is `H` instead of `h`.

Changing that will fix your problem but the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Demo using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s", Locale.ENGLISH).withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(Instant.from(dtf.parse("2013-10-31 12:10:00")).toEpochMilli());
        System.out.println(Instant.from(dtf.parse("2013-10-31 00:10:00")).toEpochMilli());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1383221400000
1383178200000
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>